# Print pyramid number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, user-interface

I want to create a pyramid number structure. Can anyone explain me how?

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var k = ' ';
  var myspace = '';
  for (j = 0; j < i - 0; j++) {
    k += i;
    myspace += ' ';
  }
  console.log(myspace + k);
}
```

I want make it like this:

```
    1
   2 2
  3 3 3
 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```js
function createPyramid(rows) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var output = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < rows - i; j++) output += ' ';
    for (var k = 0; k <= i; k++) output += (i + 1) + ' ';
    console.log(output);
  }
}

createPyramid(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below method.

```js
var a;
var n = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    document.write(j + " ");
  }
  document.write("<br />");
}
```